# Simulate network request timeout between docker containers

Tags: macos, docker, connection, timeout

I have 2 docker containers running in my desktop(Java app and RabbitMQ). I want to simulate situation when Java app cannot connect RabbitMQ(but I do not want to stop RabbitMQ). 
I found that such a command possibly can be used 
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 5672 -j DROP`

But I need an analogy of it for MacOS. Or another way to break the connection between 2 docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't run on MacOS, rather it runs in a Linux VM running on MacOS. So you can perform your commands on that VM. A common networking debugging image I use is nicolaka/netshoot (you can see more about the included utilities and and example usage in the [github repo](https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot)).

For iptables on the embedded Linux VM, you can run a command along the lines of:

```
docker run --rm --net host --privileged nicolaka/netshoot iptables ...
```